# Angular: error al cargar Angular/Material con el comando ng add @angular/material

Tags: angular, angular-material

Al ejecutar el comando ng  add @angular/material, salta el siguiente error:

```
PS C:\AngularVAXI\mi_web_app - copia> ng add @angular/material
Skipping installation: Package already installed
? Choose a prebuilt theme name, or "custom" for a custom theme: Indigo/Pink        [ Preview: https://material.angular.io?theme=indigo-pink ]
? Set up global Angular Material typography styles? Yes 
? Set up browser animations for Angular Material? Yes
UPDATE package.json (1375 bytes)
/ Installing packages...npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! Found: jasmine-core@3.5.0
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   dev jasmine-core@"~3.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   jasmine-core@"^3.5.0" from karma-jasmine@3.3.1
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine@"~3.3.0" from the root project
npm ERR!     peer karma-jasmine@">=1.1" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR!     node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!       dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer jasmine-core@">=3.8" from karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.7.0
npm ERR! node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!   dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: jasmine-core@5.0.1
npm ERR! node_modules/jasmine-core
npm ERR!   node_modules/karma-jasmine-html-reporter
npm ERR!     dev karma-jasmine-html-reporter@"^1.5.0" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! See C:\Users\FabianCBarrio\AppData\Local\npm-cache\eresolve-report.txt for a full report.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\FabianCBarrio\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-07-15T18_10_43_298Z-debug-0.log
× Package install failed, see above.
The Schematic workflow failed. See above.
PS C:\AngularVAXI\mi_web_app - copia>
```

Creo que este error se debe a distinas incompatibilidades en la dependencias del fichero package.json, pero el mensaje de error no me dice exactamente que versiones de jasmine-core y de karma-jasmine,  tengo que utilizar en mi proyecto

Answer (score 0):

He probado a instalarlo en un proyecto nuevo y no ha dado problemas, te paso el package.json para que compruebes las versiones.

Espero que te sirva.
¡Un saludo!

```
{
  "name": "test01",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/common": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/core": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/material": "^16.1.5",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.1.0",
    "@angular/router": "^16.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~7.8.0",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.13.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.1.4",
    "@angular/cli": "~16.1.4",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^16.1.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~4.3.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~4.6.0",
    "karma": "~6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.2.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-jasmine": "~5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~2.1.0",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
  }
}
```